# Error in Heidisql for mysql

Tags: mysql

Can I get some help de bugging this query I am getting error 1064 on line 2:

```
use MyDB CREATE TABLE 'room_table' 
    ( 'id' int(10) unsigned auto_increment primary key not null,
      'created_by' int(10)unsigned not null, 'created_at' datetime not null,
      'updated_by' int(10) unsigned, 'updated_at' datetime, 
      'deleted_by' int(10) unsigned, 'deleted_at' datetime, 
      'type' varchar(14) not null,
      'order' int(10) unsigned not null, 'level' char(1) not null, 
      'length' int unsigned, 'width' int unsigned, 
      'description' varchar(255)
   ),
   show tables;
```

Comment: **NEVER** use `'` quotes on a table/field names. That turns them into strings and they're no longer treated as table/field names. If you insist on quoting them all, then use backticks (`)

Comment: Or: if you insist on using quoted identifiers, turn on ANSI mode and use the standard double quotes `"`

Answer (score 0):

You are using quote `'` for table name while it is not needed at all and cause the error

```
CREATE TABLE room_table
```

You could surround table name with backticks if you are going to use a mysql reserved keyword which is not your case

Comment: This will not work either                                        use MyDB
CREATE TABLE room_table (
    id int(10) unsigned auto_increment primary key not null,  created_by int(10)unsigned not null, 
    created_at datetime not null,updated_by int(10) unsigned, updated_at datetime,
    deleted_by int(10) unsigned, deleted_at datetime, type_ varchar(14) not null,  
    order_ int(10) unsigned not null, level char(1) not null, length_ int  unsigned,
    width int unsigned, description varchar(255)),

show tables;